# Rails: Gemspec is not valid. Please fix this gemspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemspecs

When I install a gem from github it gives me the error:

```
number_internationalizer at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@number_internationalizer/bundler/gems/number_internationalizer-c0d642b04e87 did not have a valid gemspec.
This prevents bundler from installing bins or native extensions, but that may not affect its functionality.
The validation message from Rubygems was:
  "FIXME" or "TODO" is not a description
```

The gemspec is:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'number_internationalizer/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |gem|
  gem.name          = "number_internationalizer"
  gem.version       = NumberInternationalizer::VERSION
  gem.authors       = ["Myself"]
  gem.email         = ["myemail@email.com"]
  gem.description   = %q{Internationalize numbers adding normalization, validation and modifying the number field to restor the value to its original if validation fails}
  gem.summary       = gem.description
  gem.homepage      = ""

  gem.files         = `git ls-files`.split($/)
  gem.executables   = gem.files.grep(%r{^bin/}).map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
  gem.test_files    = gem.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  gem.require_paths = ["lib"]
end
```

How can I fix that error?

Comment: How did you solve this problem ? i'm having such a similar one !

Answer (score 6):

The error seems out of sync with the gemspec you show, the error indicates the `gem.descripton` is invalid. According to the error, you are using the Gem from git, which has a [commit fixing the invalid gem.description](https://github.com/bishma-stornelli/number_internationalizer/commit/65c5669a2f0e8386087c305bb1eec91cb174b6e5).

Have Bundler update to the latest `number_internationalizer` commit:

```
bundle update
```

Comment: I did that and now I get `Could not find i18n-0.6.1 in any of the sources` when trying to run `rails s`. I run `bundle show i18n` and the answer is `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@number_internationalizer/gems/i18n-0.6.1`. I'm not sure why that `@number_internationalizer` is appearing.

Comment: I found the solution to the new error. I had used `rvm gemset use number_internationalizer` before. I had to reset rvm.

Answer (score 5):

this answer is not for all situations but if you have sth like this in you `blob.gemspec` file:

```
  spec.summary       = "TODO: Write a short summary, because Rubygems requires one."
  spec.homepage      = "TODO: Put your gem's website or public repo URL here."
```

you should remove "TODO" word from it and also provide a valid HTTP URI for `spec.homepage`, you can just replace it like this:

```
  spec.summary       = "Write a short summary, because Rubygems requires one."
  spec.homepage      = "http://website.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly feel there is a check for `TODO` or `FIXME` while the interpreter is parsing your gemspec. This check has been programmed to throw an error if it sees any one of these two words. I had this same issue and I resolved it by removing any reference to TODO in my gemspec. I put a valid uri in the homepage session and everything started working fine again

Comment: changed `TODO` with `FART` and `bundle install` was succesfull

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [Ashkan Nasirzadeh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59238377/10907864).

I had a similar when working with Rails Engines in a Rails 6.0.2.2 Application.

**The trick is to**:

1. Remove every occurrence of `TODO` in the `your_engine.gemspec` file.
2. Add a website of your choice in double-quotes to the `spec.homepage`.
3. Ensure that you maintain the double quotes around the values where you removed every occurrence of `TODO` to avoid the `undefined method of for main:Object` error.

Below is a sample `your_engine.gemspec` file that has been properly modified.

```
$:.push File.expand_path("lib", __dir__)

# Maintain your gem's version:
require "app_component/version"

# Describe your gem and declare its dependencies:
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name        = "app_component"
  spec.version     = AppComponent::VERSION
  spec.authors     = ["Promise Preston"]
  spec.email       = ["promise@gmail.com"]
  spec.homepage    = "http://website.com"
  spec.summary     = "Summary of AppComponent"
  spec.description = "Description of AppComponent"
  spec.license     = "MIT"

  # Prevent pushing this gem to RubyGems.org. To allow pushes either set the 'allowed_push_host'
  # to allow pushing to a single host or delete this section to allow pushing to any host.
  if spec.respond_to?(:metadata)
    spec.metadata["allowed_push_host"] = "Set to 'http://mygemserver.com'"
  else
    raise "RubyGems 2.0 or newer is required to protect against " \
      "public gem pushes."
  end

  spec.files = Dir["{app,config,db,lib}/**/*", "MIT-LICENSE", "Rakefile", "README.md"]

  spec.add_dependency "rails", "~> 6.0.2", ">= 6.0.2.2"

  spec.add_development_dependency "sqlite3"
end
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**.